# How to properly use "or" in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to set the variable numberOfDays equal to the number of days in the month.  However, the elif statement has a flaw.  I am clearly not using the "or" statement correctly because because when I enter anything, it always says that numberOfDays is equal to 30.

```
   monthSelection = input("Enter the month you wish to view: ")

   if monthSelection == "February":
        numberOfDays = 28
   elif monthSelection == "April" or "June" or "September" or "November":
        numberOfDays = 30
   else:
        numberOfDays = 31
```

Is there any way to reformat this code to make it functional?

Comment: change to `elif monthSelection in ("April", "June",  "September", "November"):`

Comment: It's not a statement, it's a logical connective; it goes between two things that can be true-ish or false-y. `a == b or c` means "a equals b, or c is truth-y".

Comment: Except that `"September"` and `"November"` are probably never evaluated if `"June"` evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score -1):

Use `in` rather than `or`:

```
if monthSelection == "February":
    numberOfDays = 28
elif monthSelection in ("April", "June", "September", "November"):
    numberOfDays = 30
else:
    numberOfDays = 31
```

Otherwise, you need to specify each equality separately:

```
if monthSelection == "February":
    numberOfDays = 28
elif monthSelection == "April" or monthSelection == "June" or monthSelection == "September" or monthSelection == "November":
    numberOfDays = 30
else:
    numberOfDays = 31
```

Comment: Please always explain why this solves the issue and why `or` doesn't work.

Comment: Let me guess `"November"` would be the complete expression of the rightmost `or` and evaluates to `true`?